# Grails json views : opaque view selection - picks out default template in another directory

Tags: grails, view, controller

I am using Grails 3.3.9 and json views 1.2.10.

In another test I have a url mapping like this

```
    "/api/test"(resources:'test')
```

And I have an empty views/test folder, and I don't have a Test domain object.

But I do have a Device domain entity, and have a views/device/_device.gson template in that directory to help render a device object.

The TestController's show action looks like this

```
def show (Device device) {
    if(device == null) {
        render status:404
    } else {
        respond device}
}
```

This looks for a Device in domain model and populates into Shows parameter list, and I respond with the device.

There is however no show.gson in the views/test directory (it's empty).

However when you hit the url in the browser "http://localhost:8080/api/test/1", grails renders a response using the "views/device/_device.gson" template.

This is very confusing as it's very hard to figure exactly view view respond is actually using (unless you force it using a view:'xxx' map variable.

How/why is the TestController/show action response return,  picking up "views/device/_device.gson" template ?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

Step 1) if you create a new controller (I used `grails create-controller <controller>`, and then edit the generated controller to extend from `RestfulController<domain type>` (but don't override any methods).  Then Setup the URL mapping for your controller, in my example this was

```
"/api/org"(resources:'OrgRoleInstance')
```

for which I have the corresponding domain class 'OrgRoleInstance' in my model.

The create-controller action also generates an empty view package 'views/orgRoleInstance' (no gson files are generated)

a) if you do the run app now and open the url

```
http://localhost:8080/api/org
```

then your still get a rendered response (like this) !

```
[{"id":1,"sites":[],"domains":[],"role":{"enumType":"com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance$OrgRoleType","name":"Service_Provider"},"name":"Vodafone","mags":[{"id":2}]},{"id":2,"sites":[],"domains":[],"role":{"enumType":"com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance$OrgRoleType","name":"Maintainer"},"name":"Cisco","mags":[{"id":1}]},{"id":3,"sites":[],"domains":[],"role":{"enumType":"com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance$OrgRoleType","name":"Supplier"},"name":"Cisco","mags":[]},{"id":4,"sites":[{"id":1},{"id":2}],"domains":[{"id":1}],"role":{"enumType":"com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance$OrgRoleType","name":"Customer"},"name":"Acme","mags":[]}]
```

Ipso facto there is some 'default framework logic' that tries to render the default implementation of the 'index' (and 'show' etc) action inherited from RestfulController'.  This is done even with with no pre-existing gson - no warnings are provided.

Step 2: next stop the app (it's still caching the previous 'default' behaviour).

Now go to the empty view directory and create an 'index.gson' like this with no model

```
json ([1,2,3])
```

Then restart the app in your IDE.  Now when it starts, it detects that an index.gson exists, and when you call the url 'http://localhost:8080/api/org' what you get is the rendered json for the static list [1,2,3]

step 3:  gson views are using static compilation under the covers and very fiddly to get exactly right.  However in the case of default RestfulController index action , a list of OrgRoleInstances is selected from the domain model and passed as a lit to the view.  if you want the databinding to the view to work, then if your domain object is type T, the you get a `List<T>` returned.

The internal default in the code base, is if you get `List<T>` returned to respond then, the data model in the view is assumed to be `List<T> <T>List` i.e. in my example this would be

`List<OrgRoleInstance> orgRoleInstanceList` in the gson view model.  Now with a revised index.gson (you can edit this without stop/start of server in dev mode)

```
import com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance

model {
    List<OrgRoleInstance> orgRoleInstanceList
}

json {

    recordCount orgRoleInstanceList.size()
}
```

Now when you Get the URL you get a json response with the size of the list:

```
{"recordCount":4}
```

Note that if you add an extra variable to your model like this:

```
import com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance

model {
    List<OrgRoleInstance> orgRoleInstanceList
    Integer orgRoleInstanceCount
}

json {

    recordCount orgRoleInstanceList.size()
    size orgRoleInstanceCount
}
```

and modify the index.gson to print the new Integer variable - then it is not data bound from the default respond action.

Browser response looks like this:

```
{"recordCount":4,"size":null}
```

Option 4: - look at invoking a 'template' class. Having set up a model that's expecting a `List<T>`, the runTime type built via data binding is an instance of "grails.orm.PagedResultList".  This is an Iterable type.

This is very confusing to read in the documentation - it's really not clear however if you create a file called `_<file>.gson`. Then this is treated is a template gson file.

This can have its own model/json, but because all this is statically compiled you have to get the types exactly matching and where necessary declare the 'name' of the model variable when calling the template (either via g.render or implicit `tmpl.<file>`.

When you call the template from the parent view you can pass either an the `List<T>` iterable model type or iterate in the parent view and pass each `<T>` to the template.  You have to ensure that the model type you pass to the tmpl is declared as the same type in the tmpl model.

e.g. assuming a `List<T>` in the parent view but a `<T>` in the template, you need to invoke the tmpl for each item in the list.  e.g. 
if you have a tmpl like this "_orgRoleInstance.gson".

If you have the parent view like this (note single `<T>` declared and model variable named 'org'

```
import com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance

model {
    OrgRoleInstance org
}
json {
    id org.id
    name org.name
}
```

Then the parent view "index.gson" you need something like this that invokes the tmpl as many times as you have entries in the list, but I've had to tell the framework that the tmpl model variable name is 'org' by passing a map.  This will render as you expect.

```
import com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance

model {
    List<OrgRoleInstance> orgRoleInstanceList
    Integer orgRoleInstanceCount
}

orgRoleInstanceList.each { OrgRoleInstance org ->
    json tmpl.orgRoleInstance(org:org)
}
```

If you declare the tmpl variable to be "def org", it still works but as this is statically typed, the variable is passed as static instance of Object (run time type is correct, but you cant just access the properties as the static type is Object), and it gets hard sorting out the casts required to access the properties.

If you want the parent view to pass the model `List<T>` variable to the tmpl, you can = but you have to ensure that the model variable in the tmpl is `List<T>` else the data binding doesn't work.

Now in the template you can invoke the json and iterate over the List

e.g. with a modified tmpl like this

```
import com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance

model {
    //OrgRoleInstance org
    List<OrgRoleInstance> orgs
}
json {
    id orgs.id
    name orgs.name
}
```

and a revised parent view like this to invoke the tmpl:

```
import com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance

model {
    List<OrgRoleInstance> orgRoleInstanceList
    Integer orgRoleInstanceCount
}

/*
orgRoleInstanceList.each { OrgRoleInstance org ->
    json tmpl.orgRoleInstance(orgs:org)
}*/

//alternate approach
json tmpl.orgRoleInstance (orgs:orgRoleInstanceList)
```

What get rendered is this:

```
{"id":[1,2,3,4],"name":["Vodafone","Cisco","Cisco","Acme"]}
```

You will note that there is a single json clause so it iterates all the ids first and the all the names second.

If this is not what you want you have to iterate over the list to do each in turn

i.e. a modified tmpl like this will iterate over each entry in turn

```
import com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance

model {
    //OrgRoleInstance org
    List<OrgRoleInstance> orgs
}
json (orgs) {OrgRoleInstance org ->
        id org.id
        name org.name
}
```

and produce this in the browser

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Vodafone"},{"id":2,"name":"Cisco"},{"id":3,"name":"Cisco"},{"id":4,"name":"Acme"}]
```

For anyone else who is confused by Grails Views, I hope this shows how this works between url mappings (you can use the Gradle "urlMappingsReport" to see these) and shows what urls are mapped to what actions.  You then need gson views created with the same name as these actions, and configure your gson views and any tmpl you create to be aware of the implicit behaviour that the JsonViews applies when processing your code.